# Change fragment and navigation drawer state from fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created an application with navigation drawer using this tutorial: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

And I have a button on the first fragment. So, I want to change fragment by clicking the button. This code can change fragment but not change navigation draver state (title, selected item):

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

public FirstFragment(){}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_today, container, false);

    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ImageButton addButton = (ImageButton) getView().findViewById(R.id.add_button);

    addButton.setOnClickListener(new addNewListener());

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

private class addNewListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        final FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.frame_container, new NewFragment(), "NewFragmentTag");
        ft.commit();
    }
}
}
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You do not expose any callback upon `NavigationDrawer`'s item's click.

Comment: Make interface for button click and implement to your main activity so you can access the navigation drawer list item and make it to selected/unselected.

Comment: Thank you for comment. But I dont understand. What do you mean? Can you please show how to do it?